# split string in java based on some values

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have following string :

```
String verifyPaymentDetails = "{
2298597={mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00,   mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL}, 
6503939={mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}
}"
```

and I want to split the string and get the values like : `2298597` and `={mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00,   mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL},` how to do this in java using string.split ?

and after splitting the value I have replace the `{}` in value.

kindly extend your help to do this.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
String verifyPaymentDetails = "{"
    + "2298597={mihpayid=403993715508098532, request_id=NULL, bank_ref_num=NULL, amt=53.77, disc=0.00,   mode=CC, PG_TYPE=AXIS, card_no=512345XXXXXX2346, name_on_card=emu, udf2=0, addedon=2013-06-03 17:34:42, status=failure, unmappedstatus=failed, Merchant_UTR=NULL, Settled_At=NULL},"
    + "6503939={mihpayid=Not Found, status=Not Found}" + "}";
String[] split = verifyPaymentDetails.substring(1,
    verifyPaymentDetails.length() - 2).split("(\\}, ?|=\\{)");
```

Comment: This doesn't give you the = token that he wants, and also gives you tokens like `Settled_At=NULL}, \n6503939`

Comment: Why did you downvote? it was almost right and would show him how to do it. But I did correct it, so please try and accept this as answer.

Comment: Your right, removed my downvote thanks to your edit.

Comment: did the trick, thanks Manuel M